# customdata in plotly how to plot columns name

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

Hi i have dataframe that looks like this:

```
Grandes Cap Monétaire   Petites Cap
2022-10-01  61.40   11.68   26.92
2022-11-01  58.63   12.27   29.10
2022-12-01  58.36   11.75   29.89
2023-01-01  55.28   13.51   31.21
2023-02-01  57.27   12.60   30.13
2023-03-01  55.92   12.08   32.01
2023-04-01  46.84   11.71   41.45
2023-05-01  46.92   12.87   40.21
2023-06-01  46.40   11.20   42.40
2023-07-01  51.59   12.65   35.75
```

I am trying to do a bar chat with plotly with this code:

```
def graph_style(style):
    fig = go.Figure(
        [go.Bar(name=col,
                x=style.index,
                y=style[col],
                customdata=style.columns,
                hovertemplate='<br>'.join(['<b>Classe: %{customdata}</b>',
                                           'Date: %{x}',
                                           'Poids: %{y:.1f}%'
                                           ])
                ) 
         for col in style.columns]
        )
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True,
                      yaxis=dict(range=[0, 100],
                                 ticksuffix='%'),
                      barmode='stack', 
                      uniformtext_mode='hide'
                      )
    fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M3",
                     tickformat="%b\n%Y", 
                     )
    return(fig)
```

but I get this strange output. I tried many options and can't get what I would like ie the name of the column.
Any help would be helpful

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you would like to display in the frame instead of "Classe: Monétaire"?

Comment: I would like to have "Petites Cap" as is shown in the graph ie the column name. It is displayed in the graph but can't get it in the hover template

Answer (score 1):

I found an other solution:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def graph_style(style):
    fig = go.Figure(
        [go.Bar(name=col,
                x=style.index,
                y=style[col],
                customdata=np.reshape([col]*style.shape[0], -1), #here 
                hovertemplate='<br>'.join(['<b>Catégorie: %{meta}</b>',
                                           '',
                                           'Date: %{x}',
                                           'Poids: %{y:.1f}%',
                                           '<extra></extra>'
                                           ])
                ) 
         for col in style.columns]
        )
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
                      yaxis=dict(range=[0, 100],
                                 ticksuffix='%'),
                      barmode='stack', 
                      uniformtext_mode='hide'
                      )
    fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M3",
                     tickformat="%b\n%Y", 
                     )
    return(fig)

graph_style(style)
```

Answer (score 0):

Data frames are available for customdata, which can be handled using meta.

> meta
> Assigns extra meta information associated with this
> trace that can be used in various text attributes.
> Attributes such as trace `name`, graph, axis and
> colorbar `title.text`, annotation `text`
> `rangeselector`, `updatemenues` and `sliders` `label`
> text all support `meta`. To access the trace `meta`
> values in an attribute in the same trace, simply use
> `%{meta[i]}` where `i` is the index or key of the
> `meta` item in question. To access trace `meta` in
> layout attributes, use `%{data[n[.meta[i]}` where `i`
> is the index or key of the `meta` and `n` is the trace
> index.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def graph_style(style):
    fig = go.Figure(
        [go.Bar(name=col,
                x=style.index,
                y=style[col],
                meta=col,
                #customdata=style.columns,
                hovertemplate='<br>'.join(['<b>Classe: %{meta}</b>',
                                           'Date: %{x}',
                                           'Poids: %{y:.1f}%',
                                           '<extra></extra>'
                                           ])
                ) 
         for col in style.columns]
        )
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True,
                      yaxis=dict(range=[0, 100],
                                 ticksuffix='%'),
                      barmode='stack', 
                      uniformtext_mode='hide'
                      )
    fig.update_xaxes(dtick="M3",
                     tickformat="%b\n%Y", 
                     )
    return(fig)

graph_style(df)
```

[image]

Comment: I did not know this...Thx a lot ! where is there examples just to learn more about this ???

Comment: We obtained the findings of this response from the Plotly community. A search did not find the answer I saw. A similar answer can be found [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/hovertemplate-does-not-show-name-property/36139). You can also try searching for `customdata` or `meta` in the search window.

Comment: i find an other solution which is: '''               customdata=np.reshape([col]*style.shape[0], -1),
                hovertemplate='<br>'.join(['<b>Catégorie: %{customdata}</b>',
                                           '',
                                           'Date: %{x}',
                                           'Poids: %{y:.1f}%',
                                           '<extra></extra>'
                                           ])
'''